# How to sync Firebase social login user data with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a website which has a MySQL database and users are able to login to website using social media. Website allows its users to create their own quotes and list them on the website.

I am creating a mobile app for this website using Flutter. I am using Firebase Authentication for social login (Google and Facebook).

What I want to do now is fetch those quotes which user created on website and show on app and also push his quotes which he created in app to the website so that there is a sync of user data.

I've tried looking on internet but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this.

I thought of two ways:

1) New users registered in Firebase, which are not in the website's database gets inserted in website's MySQL --> I don't know how to do this.

2) I leave Firebase as it is and just hit MySQL with this email which i get during Firebase authentication and fetch/push those quotes but this problem might lead to some sync issues.

Comment: You need to add those users to your MySQL users table.  After sign in with firebase auth, you will get user information, add that info to your MySQL table.